# Dockerfile and package-json are in different folders

Tags: node.js, docker, directory, dockerfile, subdirectory

i am trying to build my react app, however, for the purpose of the project, the Dockerfile must be in the compose/cloud/ folder (it cannot be in the root), here is my folder structure

```
my-frontend-app/
│
├── compose/
│   └── cloud/
│       └── Dockerfile
│
├── src/
│   ├── components/
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── pages/
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── App.js
│   ├── index.js
│   └── ...
│
├── public/
│   ├── index.html
│   └── ...
│
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
```

here is my dockerfile

```
FROM node:18-alpine as build-stage
WORKDIR /app

RUN cd . .
RUN cd . .
COPY . compose/cloud/
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:alpine
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*
COPY --from=build-stage /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

whenever i try to build the image i keep getting this error (i run the command the build the image from inside cloud folder where Dockerfile is located)

```
#9 [build-stage 3/7] RUN cd . .
#9 DONE 0.3s

#10 [build-stage 4/7] RUN cd . .
#10 DONE 0.4s

#11 [build-stage 5/7] COPY . compose/cloud/
#11 DONE 0.0s

#12 [build-stage 6/7] RUN npm install
#12 1.414 npm ERR! code ENOENT
#12 1.414 npm ERR! syscall open
#12 1.415 npm ERR! path /app/package.json
#12 1.416 npm ERR! errno -2
#12 1.422 npm ERR! enoent Could not read package.json: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/package.json'
#12 1.422 npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
```

what should my dockerfile be? Thanks

Comment: What is `RUN cd . .` for, and why is it there twice? It does nothing, and in most shells will result in a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

A Dockerfile can only reference files relative to the build context. The build context is the directory specified as the final argument to `docker build`. Normally the Dockerfile is located at the top level of the build context, but you can use a Dockerfile located somewhere else with the `-f` option.

With your Dockerfile in `compose/cloud/Dockerfile`, you could run, from the top-level directory:

```
docker build -t my_image_tag -f compose/cloud/Dockerfile .
```

Because your build context is the top-level directory, you could do things like this:

```
COPY package.json /app/package.json
```

or:

```
COPY compose/cloud/ compose/cloud/
```

Etc.